# C++ Linked List -- how to read without repeating to same nodes

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I'm trying to read in word by word (and keep track of line numbers -- that's why I'm using getline but that's a separate problem) from a text file and getting a repeat of the last line of the file.  I think it's because I'm using getline() but I'm setting a new node every time but when I displayAll() it prints only the last line of the file. (example of some file and error at bottom). I included the Node class because that's most relevant to this issue whereas LinkedListOfFiles is mostly functions to support the full list of words once created.

```
class Node
{
public:

    string getNode(){return node;}
    void setNode(string s){node=s;}
    string getFile(){return file;}
    void setFile(string s){file=s;}
    int getNodeNumber(){return nodeNumber;}
    void setNodeNumber(int ln){if(ln<0)ln=0;nodeNumber=ln;}

    friend class LinkedListOfFiles;

    int number;
    char name; 
    Node * next;

    Node() {pLeft=NULL;pRight=NULL;}
    Node(Node * pS) {pLeft=NULL;pRight=NULL;pData=pS;}
    friend class BSTOfWords;
private:
    Node * pData;
    Node * pLeft;
    Node * pRight;

    //Node * pData;
    Node * pNext;
    Node * pPrev;
    string node;
    string file;
    int nodeNumber;
};




void LinkedListOfFiles::addFile(string fileName)
{
    int line = 0;
    ifstream InputFile;
    InputFile.open (fileName);
    string w = "",next;
    Node * wnode = new Node;
    (*wnode).setFile(fileName);

    while (!InputFile.eof())
    {
        getline(InputFile,next);
        (*wnode).setNode(next);
        line++;
        if (next == "\n"){cout<<"eof found! \n";}
        (*wnode).setNodeNumber(line);
        putAtFront (wnode);
        cout << (*wnode).getFile()+"  "+intToString((*wnode).getNodeNumber())+" "+(*wnode).getNode()+" \n";
        Node * wnode = new Node;
        wnode->pData = wnode->pNext;
    }
    //cout << " outbound to file list: "+(*wnode).getFile()+" \n";
}


void LinkedListOfFiles::putAtFront(Node * ps )
{
    insert(ps,pFront);
}


void LinkedListOfFiles::insert(Node * pNewWords, Node * pFound)
{
    Node * pNewNode;
    pNewNode = new Node;
    (*pNewNode).pData=pNewWords;

    (*((*pFound).pNext)).pPrev=pNewNode;
    (*pNewNode).pNext=(*pFound).pNext;
    (*pNewNode).pPrev=pFound;
    (*pFound).pNext=pNewNode;
}

string LinkedListOfFiles::displayAll()
{
    string result;

    // pointer to current node
    Node * pCurrentNode;

    // make current node the first item in list
    pCurrentNode = (*pFront).pNext;  //pFront points to the sentinal, it's pNext points to the first item in list

    while((*pCurrentNode).pData != NULL)
    {
        result+= (*((*pCurrentNode).pData)).getFile(); //add the currrent node's fileName
        result+="   ";
        result+= intToString((*((*pCurrentNode).pData)).getNodeNumber()); //add the currrent node's lineNumber
        result+="   ";
        result+= (*((*pCurrentNode).pData)).getNode(); //add the currrent node's line of text
        result+="   ";

        result+= "\n";
        pCurrentNode = (*pCurrentNode).pNext;
    }

    return result; // return the string with all the data
}
```

Here's a file and an example of the error it would generate

```
Some say the world will end in fire,
Some say in ice.
From what I've tasted of desire
I hold with those who favour fire.
But if it had to perish twice,
I think I know enough of hate
To say that for destruction ice
Is also great
And would suffice.
```

And the error is

```
test.txt   9   And would suffice.
test.txt   9   And would suffice.
test.txt   9   And would suffice.
test.txt   9   And would suffice.
test.txt   9   And would suffice.
test.txt   9   And would suffice.
test.txt   9   And would suffice.
test.txt   9   And would suffice.
test.txt   9   And would suffice.
```

I'm trying to learn C++ and linked lists right now.  These may be similar (if they help you in reviewing this issue) [Linked List From Text File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632902/linked-list-from-text-file?rq=1) [want to read more than 50,000 txt files and save them in linked list in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429621/want-to-read-more-than-50-000-txt-files-and-save-them-in-linked-list-in-c)  but are different because I may not be using the pointers properly to keep each node as I advance (some pointers may point back to self).

Comment: First, don't knock yourself for using std::getline(). The alternatives are almost all hideous, and it is a most-awesome standard library function. That said, **do** knock yourself for using `.eof()`. It is almost *never* correct in a loop eval condition, and my immediate take is this is no exception to that rule. See [this question and answer list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong) for more information as to why.

Comment: The error is almost certainly in the insert method, which has to be some of the most complicated pointer code I've seen. It's far too complicated for a simple linked list. Anyway, `pFound` seems to be quite important but nothing in your post explains what it is or how it gets it's value. Post more on that please.

Comment: @john, i don't see anymore references to pFound in the entire project. seems to only make an appearance as a parameter to insert(). do you think that insert() is the source of the error? i had insert() from a previous program that worked to insert into a linked list but seems to have issues in this case.

Comment: @stackuser, If pFound is not being used anywhere else then that is a definite error. I would rewrite insert from scratch for your new program.

Answer (score 1):

The loop in the addFile function should be:

```
while(getline(InputFile, next).good())
{
    // do stuff
}
```

If getline reaches the end of the file then the value in next will be unchanged. This is likely the cause of the repeated line.

Comment: It's interesting. What that does is starts by skipping the 1st line and then skips every other line in reading/printing (so only 1/2 of the lines printed).  And the original issue remains.

Comment: @stackuser did you remove the getline() from the body of the loop? It should only be in the while-condition. You probably have other issues, and I'll glance at those now, but should make sure this is fixed.

Comment: //while (!InputFile.eof())
 while ( getline(InputFile,next).good())
 {
  //getline(InputFile,next);
  InputFile >> next;
  (*wnode).setNode(next);     that's the way looks now and what this this does is just reads the 1st word of the line because i'm using >> operator. not sure but maybe i should putting this into some loop with an if(next=='\n') then <something> but not sure of the something. anyhow it doesn't matter because the original issue remains.